# Show inequality is correct by simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may be a bit of a silly question,

but I was wondering if there is any way to show with some simplification (without using a calculator) that clearly

$32-16\sqrt2 < 8\sqrt2$

(since it doesn't seem to be immediately obvious, at least for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stated inequality is equivalent to $32<24\sqrt{2}$, which in turn is equivalent to $4<3\sqrt{2}$. This last inequality can be verified by squaring both sides.

Comment: Ah thanks, this was what I was looking for!